# 1. To create a Macro that looks up a value in sheet 1 from sheet 2

Tags: excel, vba

Q. To create a Macro that looks up a value in sheet 1 from sheet 2

1. To look up for a value in Sheet 1, column "F" from rows 11 to 1000000.

   - Look up value in column "C" Sheet 1, rows 11 to 1000000 condition "Only cells having interior color index RED"
   - Table array in Sheet 2 column "C & D", rows 4 to 1000000.
2. To create a Button in Sheet 1 and Assign this Macro to to the Button.

VBA code

```
Sub VA01()
    ' CREATING SALES ORDER
    Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C11:C1000000").Select
    finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    For x = 11 To finalrow
        If Cells(x, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
            Cells(x, 6).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(R11C3:R1000000C3,Sheet2!R4C3:R1000000C4,2,0)"
        End If 
    Next x
End Sub
```

Running this Macro hangs up the Excel and takes more time to execute, it is not able to create the button.

Answer (score 0):

First I'd lose the 'Select' method which will require much time and resources. Also why do you select your ("C11:C1000000") Range when the code after does not use this selection ?Then i'd probably keep the vlookup part, but would only keep the value is they do not need to be updated. That would be something like:

```
Sub VA01()
' CREATING SALES ORDER
'Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C11:C1000000").Select
finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
For x = 11 To finalrow
    If Cells(x, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
        Cells(x, 6).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(R11C3:R1000000C3,Sheet2!R4C3:R1000000C4,2,0)"
        Cells(x, 6)=Cells(x, 6).Value
    End If 
Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: @PassKit Sir, Thank for your reply why Iam not able to assign this macro to a Button, pl. advice

Comment: @PassKit Sir, Dropping Range ("C11:C1000000") is ok with the code but I have to take Worksheets("sheet1") in code as I want to get the values in sheet 1 this code is OK

Comment: @PassKit Sir, Problem of adding button and assigning this macro has been solve if I use MACROVA01 or SALESORDERVA01 instead of VA01 . Thanks